# How to find out what Curl values to enter in WP remote posting script

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Found this handy little script that uses Curl and PHP to use the Wordpress XML-RPC function to post directly to my Wordpress blog. I think I have figured out where to enter most information, but there are two values I just can't figure out (not with any amount of Google searching either - so far).

Below I put the entire script, which others may use - provided by http://blog.artooro.com/2012/09/03/wordpress-api-xml-rpc-new-easy-to-use-php-class/

The two values I can't figure out are "ch" and "execute". Not sure if this is a Curl value or a PHP value.

```
class WordPress {
private $username;
private $password;
private $endpoint;
private $blogid;

private $ch;

public function __construct($username, $password, $endpoint, $blogid = 1) {
    $this->myusername = $username;
    $this->mypassword = $password;
    $this->my-site.com/xmlrpc.php = $endpoint;
    $this->1 = $blogid;


    $this->ch = curl_init($this->my-site.com/xmlrpc.php);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
}

private function execute($request) {
    curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    $response = curl_exec($this->ch);
    $result = xmlrpc_decode($response);
    if (is_array($result) && xmlrpc_is_fault($result)) {
        throw new Exception($result['faultString'], $result['faultCode']);
    }
    else {
        return $result;
    }
}

public function publish_post($title, $content, array $tags, array $categories, $status = 'publish', $date = Null) {
    // Set datetime for post
    if ($date == Null) {
        $post_date = date("Ymd\TH:i:s", time());
    }
    else {
        $post_date = $date;
    }
    xmlrpc_set_type($post_date, 'datetime');

    $params = array(
        $this->id,
        $this->myusername,
        $this->mypassword,
        array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => $status,
            'post_title' => $title,
            'post_content' => $content,
            'post_date' => $post_date,
            'terms_names' => array('category' => $categories, 'post_tag' => $tags)
        )
    );

    $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.newPost', $params);

    $response = $this->execute($request);
    return $response;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->ch` = Curl Handle, its the property that will hold the curl request handle. Its private as it will not be used outside of the class.

`$this->execute()` = Is the class method that will execute the curl request and return the result. Its private as it will not be used outside of the class.

Both are part of the class and not part of PHP internals.

**Also:**

I see a couple of problems with the code provided:

- `$this->my-site.com/xmlrpc.php = $endpoint;` should be
  `$this->endpoint = $endpoint;`
- `$this->1 = $blogid;` should be `$this->blogid = $blogid;`

Plus change references to them properties within the `publish_post()` method.

**Fixed code:**

```
<?php 
/*Usage:*/
$wordpress = new WordPress($username, $password, 'my-site.com/xmlrpc.php', 1);
$wordpress->publish_post(...);


class WordPress {
    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $endpoint;
    private $blogid;
    private $ch;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $endpoint, $blogid = 1) {
        $this->myusername = $username;
        $this->mypassword = $password;
        $this->endpoint   = $endpoint;
        $this->blogid     = $blogid;

        $this->ch = curl_init($this->endpoint);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
    }

    private function execute($request) {
        curl_setopt($this->ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        $response = curl_exec($this->ch);
        $result   = xmlrpc_decode($response);
        if (is_array($result) && xmlrpc_is_fault($result)) {
            throw new Exception($result['faultString'], $result['faultCode']);
        }
        else {
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function publish_post($title, $content, array $tags, array $categories, $status = 'publish', $date = Null) {
        // Set datetime for post
        if ($date == Null) {
            $post_date = date("Ymd\TH:i:s", time());
        }
        else {
            $post_date = $date;
        }
        xmlrpc_set_type($post_date, 'datetime');

        $params = array(
            $this->blogid,
            $this->myusername,
            $this->mypassword,
            array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'post_status' => $status,
                'post_title' => $title,
                'post_content' => $content,
                'post_date' => $post_date,
                'terms_names' => array('category' => $categories, 'post_tag' => $tags)
            )
        );

        $request = xmlrpc_encode_request('wp.newPost', $params);

        $response = $this->execute($request);
        return $response;
    }

}
?>
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @LawrenceCherone for the help. Much appreciated. So from you answer I'm assuming I don't edit the "ch" or the "execute" as these simple Curl instructions?

Comment: I'm speechless - thank you so much @LawrenceCherone - why doesn't SOF have a quick donation link on every answer like this so we can fire off a donation via Paypal? I mean SOF could take a small skim, someone like you can get a donation. It's a triple win.

Comment: No probs just glad to help. Dont forget to accept if you can :)

Comment: I would love to accept @LawrenceCherone, but for the life of me I can't find where I do that. Doesn't get more NEWB than that I suppose. Uh - got it!!